# Proc tabulate,in my column i have more than 50 variable how can i reduce it to only 5?

Tags: sas

```
proc tabulate data=D.Arena out=work.Arena ;
    class Row1 Column1/  order=freq   ;
    table Row1,Column1 ;  
    run;
```

after running this i received these results and now i want to restrict the columns to only 5 variables

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a 'where' statement to restrict the `col1` values being tabulated.

You can restrict based on a value property such as *starts with the letter A*

```
where col1 =: 'A';
```

You can restrict based on a value list:

```
where col1 in ('Apples', 'Lentils', 'Oranges', 'Sardines', 'Cucumber');
```

Sample data:

```
data have;
  call streaminit(123);

  array col1s[50] $20 _temporary_ (
  "Apples" "Avocados" "Bananas" "Blueberries" "Oranges" "Strawberries" "Eggs" "Lean beef" "Chicken breasts" "Lamb" "Almonds" "Chia seeds" "Coconuts" "Macadamia nuts" "Walnuts" "Asparagus" "Bell peppers" "Broccoli" "Carrots" "Cauliflower" "Cucumber" "Garlic" "Kale" "Onions" "Tomatoes" "Salmon" "Sardines" "Shellfish" "Shrimp" "Trout" "Tuna" "Brown rice" "Oats" "Quinoa" "Ezekiel bread" "Green beans" "Kidney beans" "Lentils" "Peanuts" "Cheese" "Whole milk" "Yogurt" "Butter" "Coconut oil" "Olive oil" "Potatoes" "Sweet potatoes" "Vinegar" "Dark chocolate"
  );

  do row1 = 1 to 20;
    do _n_ = 1 to 1000;
      col1 = col1s[ceil(rand('uniform',50))];
      x = ceil(rand('uniform',250));
      output;
    end;
  end;
run;
```

Frequency tabulation, also showing ALL counts

```
* col1 values shown in order by value;
proc tabulate data=have;
  class     row1 col1;
  table ALL row1,col1;
run;

* col1 values shown in order by ALL frequency;
proc tabulate data=have;
  class     row1;
  class     col1 / order=freq;
  table ALL row1,col1;
run;

* Letter T col1 values shown in order by ALL frequency;
proc tabulate data=have;
  where col1 =: 'T';
  class     row1;
  class     col1 / order=freq;
  table ALL row1,col1;
run;
```

A top 5 only list of Col1s would require a step that determines which col1s meet that criteria.  A list of those col1s can be used as part of a where `in` clause.

```
* determine the 5 col1s with highest frequency count;
proc sql noprint outobs=5;
  select 
    quote(col1) into :top5_col1_list separated by ' '
  from 
    ( select col1, count(*) as N from  have
      group by col1 
    )
  order by N descending;
quit;

proc tabulate data=have;
  where col1 in (&top5_col1_list);
  class     row1;
  class     col1 / order=freq;
  table ALL row1,col1;
run;
```

Col1s in order of value
[image]

Col1s in order of frequency
[image]

T Col1s
[image]

Top 5 Col1s
[image]

Comment: Hey, in the where statement you are actually providing the name of the column, is it possible to make this dynamic? some how we can just find the top 5 columns.

Comment: How do you define the `col1` values that correspond to a  *top 5* concept? In the answers sample code the statistic is `N`, should top 5 be the `col1`'s with highest 'N' over all the rows? Using a `where` to restrict data processed would involved a step prior to the tabulate, in which those `col1`'s are determined

Comment: My col1 variables are string in nature for eg. apple , jam , pine, and similarly row1 variables, i created a crosstab to calculate count of each row1 variable for col1 variable. Now since i have received the result i want to restrict my results to only five variables in col1 rather than 50 variable.

Comment: Improve the question by editing it and adding some sample data.  I think you want a col1='apple' to appear only if 'apple' is in the top-5 most common, frequency-wise -- But data would really clear up what you are asking.

Comment: hi richard i am missing few rows which has blank values, how do i make sure even those rows should appear which has all blank values in all 5 columns..

Comment: Use the option `MISSING` in the `proc` or `class` statement.  Using a `class` statement for different variables can let you be very specific on how a variable is processed as a class.  There are many conference papers and books about TABULATE, and they are very helpful in gaining understanding of this powerful PROC